# Is there any way to increase MTU size on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mtu

After researching a lot with no positive result on Google, it made me post a question here.

I would like to know if there is a way to **negotiate the MTU size with a BLE peripheral**.

I am using `Plugin.BLE` package in my App in order to connect to Bluetooth. Everything works fine with other devices, but however, by pairing with an iOS device, the MTU size is 20 by default, and can't be set.

This is how my code looks like when I request the MTU:

```
 await Run(async () => mtu = await device.RequestMtuAsync(512));
 Msg.Log(this, $"mtu is {mtu}");
```

Do you guys have any solution to let App negotiate the MTU size on iOS?

Comment: You cannot change the MTU. It is hardware dependent. Newer devices have a larger MTU. If you are using BLE to send a stream of data then you need to handle fragmentation and re-assembly or use an L2CAP stream.

Comment: Apple should automatically negotiate an MTU of 185 or something big. Don't you see it sending an Exchange MTU Request?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth LE connection parameters are negotiated between peers (central and peripheral) when the connection is established.  There is no API access to this process on the iOS side, but it can be changed on the other side.  By default, you get backward-compatible BLE 4.0 parameters (MTU=23, Datalength=27). If the peripheral is at least 4.2 it can negotiate and get better values.
I just tested with my iPad Pro (2018/ iOS 13.5) and I can get MTU 247 datalength 251.

Bottom line: do this on the peripheral side before you start exchanging data.

(We're doing this on Nordic nRF52840 chips, so look in the nordic apis for how to do it if this applies to you)

Comment: Connection parameters (connection interval, slave latency, timeout) have nothing to do with MTU. And Bluetooth version also does not affect MTU in any way (all versions support up to 65535 bytes at most). iOS usually initiates an MTU negotiation at the beginning of each connection with some OS-specific value. LE Data Length Extension is a separate thing that optimizes the Link Layer but does not affect MTU.

Comment: Just to clarify the data length for write operations is 3 bytes less than the MTU size.  So if the MTU is 23, the data length is 20.  If the MTU is 247 the data length is 244.