# What could be causing the Android app to stop receiving responses from the BLE device after increasing the data packet size from 4-5 bits to 140 bits?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mtu

I am using "BluetoothGatt" for BLE communication.

Previously:

The Android app received BLE responses for short BLE commands (4-5 bits) by splitting the response in the "onCharacteristicChanged" method and calling the method multiple times.
This approach worked well with short data. I was taking those split response strings and combining them into a single string to use.

Current Situation:

I am now attempting to send larger data packets (around 140 bits) to the device.
However, the app no longer receives any response from the device after increasing the data size.

I tried to increase the MTU size using the method "requestMtu(140)" before running the new command, but the "onMtuChanged" callback method always returns MTU as "96".
What could be causing this issue, and how can we resolve it?

```
BluetoothGattService myService = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("service_uuid"));
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic myChar = myService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("notification_uuid"));
            for (BluetoothGattDescriptor myDescriptor : myChar.getDescriptors()) {
                boolean result21 = myDescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                Log.e("TAG", "descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor Result2: " + result21);
                mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(myDescriptor);
            }
```

Comment: The `onMtuChanged` callback returning 96 tells you that one of your devices only supports an MTU of 96 and that's what will be used from now on

Comment: So, It's not possible to write more than 96 bits to the BLE device. right @MichaelKotzjan?

Comment: It seems that way. You always need to use the value that both devices agree to. Is it possible for you to increase the MTU size on the BLE device?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKotzjan for your kind information.
Yes, it is possible. However, we would need to get in touch with the manufacturing team in order to increase it.

Comment: I have one more question @MichaelKotzjan,
140 bit data is responding from BLE devices to iOS devices, but not to Android devices. Does this mean that the BLE device supports more than 96 bits or Android and iOS devices are handled differently on BLE devices?

Comment: I'm no expert on iOS, but I believe iOS handles this automatically and even selects a queued writing operation if the message does not fit the MTU of the device. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68389331/7473793